# Problem rendering stacked quads on mobile - Unity

Tags: unity

I have two stacked quads that use the universal render pipeline 2D sprite unlit default material. They use a 2d normal map of a png file containing a star background that give a parallax effect on my space shooter game. they cover the full view of my camera. rendering on my test computer yields no problems,both stacked transparent backgrounds are rendered proberly on the screen, but when I test it on mobile one of the backgrounds is not rendered. Only one background is rendered even if I increase the number of backgrounds to more than two. it's as if transparency is not rendered corectly , if at all on mobile. I've set different z axis for each quad, put them in different layers, or in the same layer... same issue the same time. works on pc, not on mobile.

What could be the problem?

the pngs are black with stars here and there.

Comment: A suggestion: You can choose the target platform of the project in unityHub, which can minimize the difference between the editor environment and the actual running environment.

Comment: What do you mean when you say this is a "normal map"? Can you show us one of these images? It's unclear from your description how these are layering transparently on PC — is the black background zero alpha? Are you using additive blending?